# Confusion related to integral of a Gaussian

Tags: integration, normal-distribution

I am a bit confused about calculating the integral of a Gaussian

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}+bx+c}\:dx=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{b^{2}}{4}+c}$$

Given above is the integral of a Gaussian. The integral of a Gaussian is Gaussian itself. But what is the mean and variance of this Gaussian obtained after integration?

Comment: You are **not** computing "the integral of a Gaussian", whatever that means. You are computing the integral of a _function_ of the real variable $x$, not of a random variable. The result is the quantity on the right which can be regarded as a constant if $b$ and $c$ are known constants or as a function of two variables $b$ and $c$ if $b$ and $c$ are regarded as parameters of the integrand. So, the question you ask is meaningless: there is no mean and no variance because the result is **not** a random variable.

Comment: Sorry but where is the random variable?

Answer (score 1):

The question is only meaningful if $\Im{b} \ne 0$.  Let's say that, rather, $\Re{b} = 0$ and $b = i B$.  Now you can assign a mean/variance to the resulting Gaussian.  This, BTW, is related to the well-known fact that a Fourier transform of a Gaussian is a Gaussian.

Comment: You seem to be able to see a Gaussian random variable in the question. Where?

Comment: Not explicitly, but he did ask about a mean and variance, which may define the parameters of a Gaussian function.

Comment: Sorry but I do not get it. And why do you assume that $\Im b\ne0$? This is not necessary to get a convergent integral.

Comment: It IS necessary to get a meaningful value of a mean and variance (i.e. 1st and 2nd moments of the Gaussian).

Comment: ...of the Gaussian which might or might not be there but nobody knows where? Not what I call crystal clear...

Comment: I get it, although I think you are asking for more rigor than the OP is asking.  I understand that this is the Mathematics exchange and rigor is warranted, but in this case, I think we can let go a bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7114/discussion-between-rlgordonma-and-did)